# How can locally deleted fields also be deleted on production?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, configuration

We are using D8's [Configuration Management](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management) for our site. When we delete fields in our local development environment the corresponding content type and field yml files are updated to reflect the change. However when we deploy these changes to our production environment, the field is not deleted. It is simply moved to the hidden (Disabled) spot for the content type under manage fields.

As a result we have to manually go in and delete the field in production. How can we delete the fields on production when new configuration files are deployed?

Deployment process:

1. In our local environment, make the changes by deleting the fields
2. Export config into the config/sync folder and commit into git
3. Deploy branch with latest updates to config/sync folder to Cloud environment such as production
4. run `drush config-import` and select the vcs option (to import from git)
5. navigate to the content type and verify changes
6. observe that the field is hidden, not deleted.

Comment: Are you sure you emptied the `config/sync` directory on production before copying & importing? Deleting a field means (at least) one less file, so you need to make sure not just to overwrite existing files, but also to remove obsolete files.

Comment: Yes, either delete the config/sync folder fist or use rsync --delete.

Comment: @Hudri yes - the file is deleted in git and removed from the config/sync directory.

Comment: @Berdir not sure i understand what you are saying Yes to (my question or Hudri's comment), but i will try rsync --delete

Comment: To his comment. rsync --delete is only relevant if you're already using rsync to copy the config files around. If the file is not in the sync folder then it will be deleted, guaranteed, I've done that dozens of times. Something with your deploy process is not right it seems, but you need to provide more details, e.g. the exact steps/commands that you run

Comment: @Berdir i have updated the question. As for the process, could it be that if we use field on multiple content types, that Drupal will only hide the field until the field is deleted on other entities?

Comment: No, there are two config entities for a field, the storage, which exists once for a field (per entity type) and then one per bundle. deleting it on a specific bundle will delete the field.field... file, deleting it on the last bundle will delete the field.storage... file. I don't really know what the vcs option is on config-import, make sure that the folder that you really are importing from does not have those files anymore. I assume that you can see the relevant files being deleted on drush config export/import